# Tell PHP to enable or use GD when running script via cron

Tags: php, cron, gd

I am attempting to run a php script via cron and I'm hitting a brick wall.

When I run the php script via the command line as root, everything works correctly.
When I run the php script via the command line as the user, everything works correctly.

The error that I am getting is:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreatefromstring()

To test I created a php file that has...

```
    <?php
    var_dump(gd_info());
    ?>
```

When that file is executed via cron it again says that I have a fatal error.  "Call to undefined function gd_info()"

So at this point, I've narrowed it down to GD not loading in the cron environment, but at this point, I don't know what to do to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have multiple copies of PHP. You and root use one built with GD, cron uses another due to `PATH` environment variable inconsistencies.

As a working user (you or root), run

```
which php
```

That will give you a full path like `/usr/bin/php`. Use that path in your cron entry, eg

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!  Out of curiosity, do you by chance have any idea how I could find out what environment is being used by default for cron?

Comment: @ScottHack Run a cron script that dumps the output of `env` and `which php` to a file.